# Jenkins + PMD Failure

Tags: maven-2, jenkins, pmd

I recently set up Jenkins, it is setup to run (Java) unit tests after every commit. That works fine. However, I then tried to add support for PMD.

It runs successfully, 0 unit test errors, 210 pmd warning (which is strange because it says it completed with 0 warnings on the status page)

Here is the last part of the consold log:

Tests run: 99, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

```
[JENKINS] Recording test results
[pool-1-thread-1] INFO hudson.maven.Maven3Builder$MavenExecutionListener - 
[pool-1-thread-1] INFO hudson.maven.Maven3Builder$MavenExecutionListener - --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ krunch ---
[pool-1-thread-1] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - 
[pool-1-thread-1] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ krunch ---
[pool-1-thread-1] INFO org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.jar.JarArchiver - Building jar: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/krunch/target/krunch-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[pool-1-thread-1] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - 
[pool-1-thread-1] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - >>> maven-pmd-plugin:3.0.1:check (default) @ krunch >>>
[pool-1-thread-1] INFO hudson.maven.Maven3Builder$MavenExecutionListener - 
[pool-1-thread-1] INFO hudson.maven.Maven3Builder$MavenExecutionListener - --- maven-pmd-plugin:3.0.1:pmd (pmd) @ krunch ---
[pool-1-thread-1] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - 
[pool-1-thread-1] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - --- maven-pmd-plugin:3.0.1:pmd (pmd) @ krunch ---
[PMD] Finding all files that match the pattern pmd.xml
[PMD] Parsing 1 files in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/krunch/target
[PMD] Successfully parsed file /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/krunch/target/pmd.xml of module krunch with 210 warnings.
[CHECKSTYLE] No report found for mojo check
[pool-1-thread-1] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - 
[pool-1-thread-1] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - <<< maven-pmd-plugin:3.0.1:check (default) @ krunch <<<
[pool-1-thread-1] INFO hudson.maven.Maven3Builder$MavenExecutionListener - 
[pool-1-thread-1] INFO hudson.maven.Maven3Builder$MavenExecutionListener - --- maven-pmd-plugin:3.0.1:check (default) @ krunch ---
[pool-1-thread-1] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - 
[pool-1-thread-1] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - --- maven-pmd-plugin:3.0.1:check (default) @ krunch ---
[CHECKSTYLE] No report found for mojo check
[pool-1-thread-1] INFO hudson.maven.Maven3Builder$MavenExecutionListener - ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[pool-1-thread-1] INFO hudson.maven.Maven3Builder$MavenExecutionListener - BUILD FAILURE
[pool-1-thread-1] INFO hudson.maven.Maven3Builder$MavenExecutionListener - ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[pool-1-thread-1] INFO hudson.maven.Maven3Builder$MavenExecutionListener - Total time: 1:58.654s
[pool-1-thread-1] INFO hudson.maven.Maven3Builder$MavenExecutionListener - Finished at: Fri Aug 16 14:19:47 UTC 2013
[pool-1-thread-1] INFO hudson.maven.Maven3Builder$MavenExecutionListener - Final Memory: 38M/718M
[pool-1-thread-1] INFO hudson.maven.Maven3Builder$MavenExecutionListener - ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[JENKINS] Archiving /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/krunch/pom.xml to /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/krunch/modules/krunch$krunch/builds/2013-08-16_14-17-43/archive/krunch/krunch/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/krunch-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[JENKINS] Archiving /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/krunch/target/krunch-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar to /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/krunch/modules/krunch$krunch/builds/2013-08-16_14-17-43/archive/krunch/krunch/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/krunch-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[pool-1-thread-1] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[pool-1-thread-1] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - BUILD FAILURE
[pool-1-thread-1] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[pool-1-thread-1] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - Total time: 2:00.924s
[pool-1-thread-1] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - Finished at: Fri Aug 16 14:19:49 UTC 2013
[pool-1-thread-1] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - Final Memory: 38M/717M
[pool-1-thread-1] INFO org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger - ------------------------------------------------------------------------
channel stopped
Finished: FAILURE
```

Here is my current POM (sorry for the mess, i've been hacking at it for a while)

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.7</source>
                        <target>1.6</target>
                        <compilerId>eclipse</compilerId>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
                    <artifactId>plexus-compiler-eclipse</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>check</goal>
                        <goal>cpd-check</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>resources</directory>
        </resource>

    </resources>
</build>


<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jxr-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <linkXRef>false</linkXRef>
                <targetJdk>1.6</targetJdk>
                <rulesets>
                    <ruleset>/rulesets/basic.xml</ruleset>
                </rulesets>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

*I have looked at at least 200 web pages and just can't seem to find any documentation that works. Let me know if you need more/less info.

Comment: So jenkins archived your build successfully then failed your build.

How did you configure that job ? What lies after the archive artifacts element ? PMD ? What command do you use to run maven from jenkins ?

Comment: How did you configure that job? It's a maven job, from a private Github repo. I didn't have to setup up anything really and it worked running unit tests(everything passed etc). It was not until I added PMD that it failed. The only setting I changed was I clicked the "generate PMD reports" in the configure option. And I installed the PMD Plug-in 3.35

Comment: "What lies after the archive artifacts element?" - I'm not really sure what/where this is.  
" What command do you use to run maven from jenkins ? " - Just the default settings when I created a new Maven2 Job. Also I'm about to reformat my question.

Comment: You are using the check argument for pmd. It looks like your build will fail if the pmd report wasn't empty. http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-pmd-plugin/check-mojo.html you can configure it directly to have more information or avoid failing the build here. Have you tried running your build outside of jenkins ?

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a test. I've ran it through Eclipse, and I've ran it from the terminal with success, but I've been at it all night, so I can't say that it runs fine in its current state.

Comment: So it all works in eclipse, but in the terminal if I run `mvn pmd:pmd` or `mvn pmd:check` it fails with the following error, "An error has occurred in PMD Report report generation.", it's successful if I run `mvn pmd:cpd`. Perhaps I need to go re-read pmd commands a bit more.

Comment: By changing the goals to `<goal>pmd</goal><goal>cpd</goal>` it at least finishes successfully. I still don't see the 200+ warnings I expected to see, but i'm at further along than I was :)